# How can I pass the children of a function component to another function component in a react class?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

```
class About extends React.Component<{},{}>{
    Format = () => {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }

    Type1 = () => {
        return(
            <this.Format>
                <div>...</div>
            </this.Format>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass the `<div>...</div>` into the Format component, but I get the error: `Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'` which I can't find much about regarding this case.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, had to pass in props as parameter, since this.props refers to the class props and not the function props.

```
    Format = (props) => {
        return(
            <div>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: It is less common to write functional components like this though, as in within a class component. Normally, you would want to abstract the functional component separately into another file, so that it can be easily reused in other places.